# Connecting Apache Superset to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, apache-superset

I'm new to Superset and very excited to get started. I need to connect to my data on Microsoft SQL Server Express 2019. I did follow [these](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/docker-add-drivers) instructions. Now when I try to connect using the following connection string:

```
mssql+pymssql://ss_user:password008@100.0.0.44\SQLEXPRESS:1433/EmpDataMaster
```

I get the following error. Can someone please help?

`ERROR: (builtins.NoneType) None [SQL: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (100.0.0.44\\SQLEXPRESS)\n') (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)`

Comment: That's not how pymssql connection strings work. Pymssql is a DBAPI wrapper around FreeTDS and server names, instance names, ports, etc. are configured in the [freetds.conf file](https://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.html). i.e.: `mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<freetds_name>/`

Comment: Aside... regardless of the connection library used, choose to use either an instance name (`100.0.0.44\SQLEXPRESS`) or a port (`100.0.0.44:1433`), don't try to combine the two. If you know the port number in advance then use that, it's direct and quicker to connect. Using an instance name requires additional roundtrips - the client sends SSRP requests to the SQL Browser service listening on the target server's udp/1434 to convert the instance name to the TCP port number that it's listening on, then the client connects to that TCP port.